# Unsort Google Spreadsheet column

Tags: google-sheets

I have sorted a column from A to Z to examine what I wanted. And now I want to bring it back to its initial state. How can I do that?

Comment: Ctrl-z to undo, or revert back in the edits menu

Answer (score 1):

### Add an Index Column

Data can be sorted any number of ways.  If the data starts in an order that can't be recreated programmatically then you should add an additional column to 'tag' the existing order.  This creates an index you can later use to restore the order.

For example add a column of numbers incrementing from 1 to 'x' beside your existing data, where 'x' is the number of rows of data you have.

When sorting your data you would include this index column in your sort so that if you wanted to restore the original order you could sort based on that index column instead of your data.

Outside of this the only way to restore the original order is by undoing your changes (ctrl+z etc.) which is no longer possible once the undo history is no longer available.